# Codeigniter, uri->segment, str_len

Tags: codeigniter

I'm very new to php and mysql. I'm trying to pass the value "part(2)" to my code igniter controller. "part(2)" is one of the name of the data values in my database. After passing it to the uri segment, I extracted it using the command `$value = str_replace("%20", " ", $this->uri->segment(5));` . Now when i search my database using the variable $value, it's not displaying the results. I presume the problem is with having using "()". I am wondering if it has anything to do with the data type utl8 vs latin1. My database is configured to use latin1_general_ci. I have tried changing the database field type to utl8_general_ci, but it does not work. Can anyone please help me out here?.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `var_dump($value)` just to see what it contains?

Also, the result from `$this->db->last_query();` might be useful to see what you are actually quering your database for. I don't see a reason why you couldn't put perenthesis in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure both utf8 and latin1 are fine.
can you post your controller code?

firstly, if you are passing the value in your uri, do you have `()` in your permitted uri characters in `application/config/config.php`?

something like this:
`$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-()';`

But I just tried this and my values came out with html entities: `part&#40;2&#41;` instead..

you can fix this with something like this:

```
input_value = html_entity_decode($input_value);
```